# create a random sequence, skip to any part of the sequence

Tags: math, random, srand

In Linux. There is an srand() function, where you supply a seed and it will guarantee the same sequence of pseudorandom numbers in subsequent calls to the random() function afterwards.

Lets say, I want to store this pseudo random sequence by remembering this seed value.

Furthermore, let's say I want the 100 thousandth number in this pseudo random sequence later.

One way, would be to supply the seed number using srand(), and then calling random() 100 thousand times, and remembering this number.

Is there a better way of skipping all 99,999 other numbers in the pseudo random list and directly getting the 100 thousandth number in the list.

thanks,

m

Comment: Note that `srand` seeds `rand`, and `srandom` seeds `random`.

Comment: I'd be interesting in knowing the use case behind this - I think I'm missing something, as I can't see why the 100,000th sequence is more random than the first.

Comment: @HorusKol It's been a while, but ending up here via google when interested in something related, I do feel like giving you a use case. Imagine a game that gives you a series of puzzles, each generated from a single number. To make sure that each person gets different puzzles, you use a random generator and you remember the initial seed. Now, you may want the user be able to continue where he left (at which time the seed is known, which makes things easier) or even to replay any puzzle as long as he remembers its number.

Comment: (Yes, I had to stretch it a little to get a complete use case. However, the idea is that it isn't about "more random" but about "recreating" something "random" (thus actually turning the pseudo-part of the randomness into an advantage)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure there's a defined standard for implementing `rand` on any platform; however, picking this one from the [GNU Scientific Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Unix-random-number-generators.html):

> — Generator: gsl_rng_rand
>
> This is the BSD rand generator. Its sequence is
>
> x<sub>n+1</sub> = (a x<sub>n</sub> + c) mod m
>
> with a = 1103515245, c = 12345 and m = 2<sup>31</sup>. The seed specifies the initial value, x<sub>1</sub>. The period of this generator is 2<sup>31</sup>, and it uses 1 word of storage per generator.

So to "know" x<sub>n</sub> requires you to know x<sub>n-1</sub>.  Unless there's some obvious pattern I'm missing, you can't jump to a value without computing all the values before it.   (But that's not necessarily the case for every `rand` implementation.)

If we start with x<sub>1</sub>...

- x<sub>2</sub> = (a * x<sub>1</sub> + c) % m
- x<sub>3</sub> = (a * ((a * x<sub>1</sub> + c) % m) + c) % m
- x<sub>4</sub> = (a * ((a * ((a * x<sub>1</sub> + c) % m) + c) % m) + c) % m
- x<sub>5</sub> = (a * (a * ((a * ((a * x<sub>1</sub> + c) % m) + c) % m) + c) % m) + c) % m

It gets out of hand pretty quickly.  Is that function easily reducible?  I don't think it is.

<sub>(There's a statistics phrase for a series where x<sub>n</sub> depends on x<sub>n-1</sub> -- can anyone remind me what that word is?)</sub>

Comment: RE: statistics phrase. Markov chain of order 1? Though not really in this case, since x_n isn't independent of x_(n-2).

Comment: This isn't a Markov chain. It's basically just a recurrence relation over the integers modulo 2^31.

Comment: BTW That recurrence relation is pretty easy to solve. Remember you can pull all of those `% m` operations out to a single application of `% m` at the end. The resulting relation is a textbook example. But turning it into an efficient and usable piece of code takes a bit more work because applying it naively requires arbitrary precision integers. But I think there may be a way to get that partly under control.

Answer (score 1):

If they're available on your system, you can use `rand_r` instead of `rand` & `srand`, or use `initstate` and `setstate` with `random`. `rand_r` takes an `unsigned *` as an argument, where it stores its state. After calling `rand_r` numerous times, save the value of this unsigned integer and use it as the starting value the next time.

For `random()`, use `initstate` rather than `srandom`. Save the contents of the state buffer for any state that you want to restore. To restore a state, fill a buffer with and call `setstate`. If a buffer is already the current state buffer, you can skip the call to `setstate`.

Answer (score 1):

This is developed from @Mark's answer using the BSD `rand()` function.

`rand1()` computes the nth random number, starting at `seed`, by stepping through n times.

`rand2()` computes the same using a shortcut. It can step up to 2^24-1 steps in one go. Internally it requires only 24 steps.

If the BSD random number generator is good enough for you then this will suffice:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const unsigned int m = (1<<31)-1;

unsigned int a[24] = {
    1103515245, 1117952617, 1845919505, 1339940641, 1601471041,
    187569281 , 1979738369, 387043841 , 1046979585, 1574914049,
    1073647617, 285024257 , 1710899201, 1542750209, 2011758593,
    1876033537, 1604583425, 1061683201, 2123366401, 2099249153,
    2051014657, 1954545665, 1761607681, 1375731713
};

unsigned int b[24] = {
    12345, 1406932606, 1449466924, 1293799192, 1695770928, 1680572000,
    422948032, 910563712, 519516928, 530212352, 98880512, 646551552,
    940781568, 472276992, 1749860352, 278495232, 556990464, 1113980928,
    80478208, 160956416, 321912832, 643825664, 1287651328, 427819008
};

unsigned int rand1(unsigned int seed, unsigned int n)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i<n; ++i)
    {
        seed = (1103515245U*seed+12345U) & m;
    }
    return seed;
}

unsigned int rand2(unsigned int seed, unsigned int n)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i<24; ++i)
    {
        if (n & (1<<i))
        {
            seed = (a[i]*seed+b[i]) & m;
        }
    }
    return seed;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%u\n", rand1 (10101, 100000));
    printf("%u\n", rand2 (10101, 100000));
}
```

It's not hard to adapt to any linear congruential generator. I computed the tables in a language with a proper integer type (Haskell), but I could have computed them another way in C using only a few lines more code.

Answer (score 0):

If you always want the 100,000th item, just store it for later.

Or you could gen the sequence and store that... and query for the particular element by index later.